# capybara 2.4.4 all('.elementIndex').each not working on IE9

Tags: selenium-webdriver, capybara

I am using:

Ruby 1.9.3

Capybara 2.4.4

Selenium-webdriver 2.47.1

I have webpage with 20 records(with pagination) and I would like to test that record with number 8 is present on current page, each record has serial number and identified by

```
<span class="elementIndex">8.</span>
```

I am using below function which works fine on 'FF'v40 and 'Chrome'v45

```
def has_answer_number?(result)
   puts "#{has_css?('.elementIndex',:text => "#{result}.")}" # IE9 returns false
   puts "#{find('.resultNumber',:text => "#{result}.")}" # IE9 gives error  Unable to find css ".resultNumber" with text "7." (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

   all('.elementIndex').each do |number_value|
     return true if number_value.text.scan(/[0-9]+/).first.to_s.eql?(result.to_s)
   end
 false
end
```

This function always returns false, even though 8th record is present on that page.

Note: I am using Win7 machine and I have done all required configurations https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver, my other test cases are running fine.

Comment: Does I.E. work on other tests and only fail on this one, or fail on all your tests?  If it fails on all tests please check the Required Configuration section of https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver especially the part about protected mode settings

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that, I have done all required configurations, protected mode settings, path etc, Other test cases where I am not using similar function are running fine.